# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database requested by the login. The login failed

Tags: c#, entity-framework

More of the exception

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "BotDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'PIXELBOT\pixelbot'.
```

Hello

I made a console applicaiton in C# which uses a database with Entity framework.

The program works just fine on my own computer, but i need the program to run 24/7, so i rented a VPS through azure.

The problem is, that the program is not working on the VPS. The VPS is all new, and totally clean. The only thing i installed is Microsoft SQL Server 2014 LocalDB Express 64 Bit. I get the exception in the top of this post.

I really have no clue whats wrong, or what i should try to do. I've been searching around, and found other threads with problems like this, but none of the solutions work so far.

My connectionstring in the program if that is relevant:

```
    <add name="BotDb"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BotDb;User Id="usernameonvps";Password="passwordtovps";Integrated Security=SSPI;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB does this path/database exist on the vps? are maybe users and/or passwords calculated differently?

Comment: Have you tried logging into your SQL 2014 local instance using SSMS with the 'Pixelbot\pixelbot' account? Then if you're in, confirmed it can access the catalog 'BotDB' with the required permissions?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro How do i check this?

Comment: @dpimente SSMS is not installed on the server. Only localdb... But i guess i could try to install it..

Answer (score 2):

Do you check MSSQL settings? Is the SQL Server authentication switched on? May be server allows Windows authentication only.

Comment: You have to walk me through this... I dont know the answer to any of the question, neither do i know where to check this..

Comment: The easiest way is to install SSMS and try to login with you credentials. If you can login then everything is OK with DB and you should search for answer in your code. If you can login only with Windows authentication you should login and try to change settings in properties of sql server (if you have rights for this opeartion). Another variant of quick check is chnge of you connection string: <add name="BotDb"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=BotDb; Integrated Security=true;"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />.

Comment: look here how to change authentication mode: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx

Comment: Okay so i installed SSMS. I could connect to the database using (localdb)\mssqllocaldb with windows authentication. I could not find a working combination with SQL server authentication... Where does this leave me?

The authentication mode is set to SQL server AND Windows authentication

Comment: Ok, windows authentication is working. Was the  authentication mode set to SQL server AND Windows authentication or you did it? If you did it do you restart server after this? Check your user settings. It should help you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337562.aspx

Comment: In the end if you did everything right you should have possibility to login in SSMS with you login and password.

Comment: It was already set to sql and windows authentication.. If i create a sql log-in i need to change Integrated Security to false, right?
Just to be 100% sure. I dont have manually to create the BotDb, do i? Right now i just have the standard "Master", "Model", "msdb" and "tempdb"

Comment: if you use sql authentication you should use your first variant of connection string with integrated security = SSPI. If you can login into DB through SSMS with you login and password it should work for you perfect. About BotDb it depends on approach you are using in your code. if you use code first approach EF generates db for you. If you use database first approach you should create your db manually.

Comment: Im using Code first. I was not able to login using SSMS using sql authentication, only windows authentication.. I really appreciate your patience and you spending your time helping me.. EDIT: Okay, i made a new login with the public and sysadmin right. I was able to login with this user using SMSS.. I will try with my program now

Comment: I think you should check the user = usernameonvps with pasword = passwordtovps in your sql server. Ok if you create a new user and cal login, i think you program should work.

Comment: Integrated Security from microsoft website: "When false, User ID and Password are specified in the connection. When true, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication." So i'll try with false i guess

Comment: So i tried with the login i just made, which now gave me this exceptio (Same as first, just with another username): ERROR: System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot open database "BotDb" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user 'SupUs'.

Comment: Do you try the same with Integrated security = true?

Comment: Just did. Then my user name and password just gets overridden and i get the same old "Login failed for user 'PIXELBOT\pixelbot'"

Comment: This is example of connection string from my PC:<add name="EmployeeDBContext"
        connectionString="server=avtomat\sqlexpress; database=Sample; integrated security=true;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/> There is small difference in it "database=Sample;" maybe you can try it?

Comment: Im probably doing something wrong... Thank you very much for your help.. I'll try to contact azure support, and see if they can help me.. I'll come back here with an asnwer when/if i get it

Comment: Okay dude.. I got it working.... Im not sure if i'll ever get over this... The problem was, that i was having a nullinitialiser in my context class: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985854/ef-code-first-creating-database-login-failed-for-user

anyways.. Thank you very much for your time and help